# How to start pool mining in Linux

Tags: mining-pools, linux, miner-configuration

I have read numerous how-to and tutorials (most of them outdated) on how to simply start mining on a pool and I wasn't be able to do it.

**Could someone simply describe/enumerate how can someone start pool-mining in a Linux OS (on any distribution) command-line (shell) ?**

Comment: Simply using cgminer and reading how to set it up will be more than enough. There is nothing special in setting up Pool'ed mining, just have the miner connect.

Answer (score 6):

BitMinter is an attempt at making just this sort of thing easier and a more pleasant experience.

1. Install Java if you don't have it, e.g. on Ubuntu `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre icedtea-netx` (the icedtea-netx is for Java WebStart)
2. If you will mine in GPUs, install the latest drivers (e.g. from amd.com)
3. If you will mine on FPGA/ASIC, give yourself access to serial ports. On Ubuntu `sudo usermod -a -G dialout USERNAME` then log out and back in.
4. Start the miner from bitminter.com website or commandline:

   `javaws http://bitminter.com/client/bitminter.jnlp`

Comment: Does BitMinter allow you to solo mine or select what pool you mine with?

Comment: Althought it need a GUI to work, it's a nice answer.
Any idea in GPU support with intel graphics card? I have OpenCl installed but it doesn't seem to recognize the intel graphics card.

Comment: Multi-pool support will come in a future version. Intel GPUs have not supported OpenCL until recently, so most won't work. I believe HD2500 and HD4000 can work, but not sure if anyone tried yet.

Answer (score 0):

you need openjdk-7 to get it work ;)