# is Bitcoind -gen solo mining ?

Tags: bitcoind, solo-mining, balance

I am running "./bitcoind -daemon -gen" in my machine . Is it solo mining ? If so, what does it take to create 1 bitcoin ? When i run "./bitcoind getbalance" it is always 0.00000 . 
"./bitecoind getmininginfo" results in:
{
    "blocks" : 319203,
    "currentblocksize" : 1000,
    "currentblocktx" : 0,
    "difficulty" : 68.59413778,
    "errors" : "",
    "generate" : true,
    "genproclimit" : -1,
    "hashespersec" : 1447,
    "networkhashps" : 2298081699,
    "pooledtx" : 0,
    "testnet" : false
}

Am i on right way ? If so, what does it take to create 1 coin ? Also, when i create a coin, how to send it to my address ? will it be automatically ?

Comment: Your setup is perfect.  All you need is a time machine to go back to 2010 and you will be set.

Comment: it is not the case for me

Comment: no time machine? sux2bu

Comment: i just want mining using command line. is it possible ? just let me know this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's solo mining, and the difficulty is so large that you will never be able to find a block before the mining pools do. You have a better chance at winning a lottery than mining a block before big pools do.

So you will most likely never get any coins.

Comment: Firstly,thanks for reply. Hmm, how can i do mining with other using command line ? do u know the command line for mining pools ?

Comment: That's a different question. Check http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4191/how-to-start-pool-mining-in-linux